# Execute entire content of a Python file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In the PySpark shell, how can I execute the entire contents of a file?

For example, for the file `MyScript.py` I would like to do something like this:

```
:run MyScript.py
```

Comment: You could either use Magic Functions like `%run` or Python Libraries such as `os.system()`, `subprocess.call()`